# Conditional PowerShell operators

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get a list where the title does not have `temp` or `temporary` or `*contractor` or `contractor*`.

This code is working, meaning I get a list which does not have temporary records.

```powershell
$pTitle = $profile["Title"]
if ($pTitle -ne "Temporary")
```

However the following code does not work when I add `-or` and `-notlike` for the wildcard.

```powershell
$pTitle = $profile["Title"]
if ($pTitle -ne "Temporary" -or $pTitle -notlike "Temporary" -or $pTitle -notlike "contractor" -or $pTitle -notlike "Temp")
```

Comment: try using `"*text*"` in `-notlike` condition

Comment: That did not help. The list still contains temporary, contractor records. if($pTitle -ne "Temporary" -or $pTitle -notlike "*temporary*" -or $pTitle -notlike "*contractor*" -or $pTitle -notlike "*temp*")

Comment: my bad the -notlike works solo but it fails with OR operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually want `-and` here. Your expression will only evaluate to false if all of the words are found currently.

Comment: FERRIL: Just figured this out. Thanks

if($pTitle -notlike "*Temporary*" -AND $pTitle -notlike "*contractor*" -AND $pTitle -notlike "*Temp*")

Answer (score 0):

```
$List  = @(1,2,3)
```

If I ask you to return all the items in the list that are:
  not equal to 1 
  or
  not equal to 2
  or
  not equal to 3

the answer will be the whole list

```
$List  | where { ($_ -ne 1) -or ($_ -ne 2) -or ($_ -ne 3) }
1
2
3
```

You are getting your logical operators mixed up.
Look at replacing -or with -and